# Creating decision tables in Red Hat Decision Central not reflecting complex types / structures

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules, redhat-brms, decision-model-notation

I have a DMN decision created in Decision Manager 7.3. I have a few data types created, all of which are "structures" (i.e. complex types) with nested fields. I have created a decision table of which the condition column is bound to one of these structures (`Customer`) and the output column is bound to a `Result` structure.

However, I would expect the column headers to reflect the structure of the objects as per the example here (step 9 onwards): https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.3/html-single/designing_a_decision_service_using_dmn_models/index#dmn-data-types-defining-proc_dmn-models

In the documentation example, the `Loan_Qualification` type has nested fields and these are shown as sub-columns in the table header.

My data types are defined as follows:
[image: Data Types]

I have a `Customer` input node and a decision node defined as follows:
[image: Input node]

[image: Decision node]

Yet in my decision table, the columns map to the top level object only as follows:
[image: Decision table]

So any ideas as to what I might be missing? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I have used the answer given below by @karreiro which works for the outcome / action column, but inserting an Input Clause left or right adds a new top level column, not a sub column, which then looks like the following:

[image: Added sub columns]

Is this something you expect the decision table editor to be able to do as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectations are correct.

The DMN editor aims to support the auto-creation of fields for Structure Data Types (for output clauses https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-3685, and input clauses https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-4491).

However, momentarily, users need to create these fields manually:

[See how to create here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as14y.gif) :-)

Comment: Please describe the creation process in your answer (in addition to the linked image).

Comment: @karreiro, thanks that worked for the Output columns but will not work for the Condition column (see me updated question) .

Comment: @JustinPhillips I'm glad the answer was helpful. The content of a input clause is a FEEL expression, but I agree that's odd to not have the nesting structure like we have in the output clause.

I will raise this concern to the UX team and to the engineering the team to check a good way to handle this.

Thanks for the feedback :-)